# Deploying JRuby/Rails to Glassfish: undefined method `bundle_path' for Bundler:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glassfish, jruby, bundler, warbler

The following error shows up in my Glassfish log when attempting to access my app:

```
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) method 'to_yaml' not defined in Object
```

Looking through the log I see this:

```
undefined method `bundle_path' for Bundler:Module
```

I confirmed that warble is definitely putting the Bundler gem in my .war file.

(using ruby 1.9, rails 3.1, glassfish 3.0 and 3.1)

This also appears in the glassfish log:

```
Policy Provider:Failed Permission Check: context (" myapp/myapp ") , permission (" (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) ") |#]
```

However I've verified that the permission is granted in server.policy.

EDIT: I fixed the permission problem and the first two errors persist. (That said, the premission problem required me to edit a file it specifically says not to edit. Attempting to grant this permission in server.policy in Glassfish did not work).

Here is the relevant environment info from the Glassfish log file: https://gist.github.com/1245825

Comment: If you're running Glassfish with a security manager enabled, can you confirm that it's not part of the problem by temporarily disabling it and deploying again?

Comment: I disabled the security manager and the error persisted.

Comment: Note that even with security manager disabled the permission check fails on ReflectPErmission suppressAccessChecks.

Comment: There seems to be an issue on github for this problem: https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues/44

Comment: I tried the fix suggested but it didn't resolve anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This affects some application servers but not others.

See this thread for further information and a quick fix.

https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues/44#issuecomment-2809940

Answer (score 0):

You can host it outside Glassfish, on a, nginx+passenger or apache2+passenger configuration, and have it proxying Glassfish. It's a win-win solution, if you don't have to integrate with any other java resource/app.